# How to Manage a task execution time in PHP

Tags: php, time, multitasking

I have 2 Tasks Task A and Task B
Task A approximately completion time is 10sec
 and same for Task B means Every Task has some Time Limit 
IF task completes within time limit then ok. but if exhausts time limit then it should be paused and second task should be executed and so on.

I am just thinking the task object should have three method as following

1. run : when starting task
2. onPause: which saves his progress
3. onResume : when task resumes how should it resumed.

So How i Should manage the time of the task?

I m thinking about on every onPause call we calculate estimated time if time runs out then we will start the next task but it has some problems so i like to know the better way to add this functionalty to my project 
Thanks in advance.

```
abstract class Task_Worker
{
protected $task;
public   $conn;
public $status;
public $action;
public $id;
public $pause_info;
public $start_time;
public $script_time;

public function __construct($task,$mysqli)
{   
    $this->start_time = microtime();
    $this->task = $task;
    $this->status = $task['task_status'];
    $this->action = $task['task_action'];
    $this->id = $task['task_id'];
    $this->run();
}
public function response($response)
{
    update("task_response='$response'","task_id=$task[id]");
}

public function onPause()
{
    $string = $this->pause_info;
    update("task_pause='$string'", "task_id=$task[id]");
}

// to be implemented for every task class
abstract protected function onResume();
abstract protected function run();
```

Comment: are your tasks are functions ? Can you please put a sudo code

Comment: We will crete tasks as object

Comment: raheel khan I have put my task object abstract class

Comment: please kindly let me know  @RaheelKhan do you need anything to figure out the question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function run()
{       
    $timeFinish = microtime(true) + 30;
    try
    {

        while(true)
        {
            checkTimeOut($timeFinish);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e-getMessage();
    }   
}


function checkTimeOut($timeFinish)
{
    if(microtime(true) > $timeFinish)
        die('Timeout');

    return true;
}

run();
```

Comment: set time limit will be set the time for that run function or full script ?

Comment: @siddhesh See if you can manage to write your function in try block.

Comment: Ok will you tell me how will you get this functionality. Forget about my code.

Comment: I will do this via javascript or will take help of http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: Will you please tell me Why we can't use registser-shutdown-function here.

Comment: You can use register_shutdown_function to call the next task. But the problem is php cannot set limit for a particular function. so may be you need to check time on each line for your method.

Comment: but whenever set limit function is called it reset counter right now if our function or object performing his task at more than set limit then we will call the shutdown function is it the right logic?  I am trying to say when our object initialize we will set time limit.

Comment: Unfortunately set_time_limit works on a global scope. Thats why i deleted my first answer.

Comment: also i guess register_function_shutdown comes under set_time_limit. Means set_limit_limit leads to fatal error: